# Facebook and Codeigniter T_OBJECT_OPERATOR error

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use the Facebook SDK (v4) with CodeIgniter.

I have done something similar to Ben Marshall's article here: http://www.benmarshall.me/facebook-sdk-php-v4-codeigniter/

I keep receiving this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in /nfs/c11/h02/mnt/198448/domains/hi.us/html/application/libraries/facebook/facebook.php on line 98

Line 98 is:

```
$request = ( new FacebookRequest( $this->session, 'GET', '/me' ) )->execute();
```

I have PHP version 5.3.29

I haven't used PHP in over 2 years so I feel like this may be a simple issue but I just cannot seem to find a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is called "class member access on instantiation" and is only available with PHP 5.4+. So you'll need to break that code up into two lines:

```
$request = new FacebookRequest( $this->session, 'GET', '/me' );
$request->execute();
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew it had to be something simple... Kind of a pain considering the whole SDK is written this way. I guess I'll just use an older SDK if possible or switch web hosts.